# Xdebug aguardando sessão eternamente no eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, debug

Estou tentando debugar um sistema feito em php utilizando o Xdebug. Segui as instruções de instalação descomentando e alterando as configurações do Xdebug no php.ini:

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.5-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_connect_back= 1
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_port= 9669
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

No entanto ao tentar rodar o sistema no eclipse, ele fica eternamente aguardando sessão, não debugando o código.

No site do xdebug, utilizei a análise do phpinfo() e ele me retornou a seguinte saída:

```
Xdebug installed: 2.3.3
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC11 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.5.27
Zend API nr: 220121212
PHP API nr: 20121212
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
Configuration File: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: C:\xampp\php\ext
```

Pesquisei sobre este problema, porém até agora não consegui acertar a configuração para que o xdebug funcione.